# Android studio, adding multiple markers and when each marker are clicked, it will open a new activity class

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

The **onInfoWindowCLick** said that it is never used. Please help me

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {


    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private Map<Marker, Class> allMarkersMap = new HashMap<Marker, Class>;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Marker marker1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, -0))
                .title("Netherlands")
                .snippet("Amsterdam"));
        allMarkersMap.put(marker1, MainActivity.class);

    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker1) {
        Class cls = allMarkersMap.get(marker1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, cls);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution for multiple markers

```
ArrayList<MarkerData> markersArray = new ArrayList<MarkerData>();

for(int i = 0 ; i < markersArray.size() ; i++ ) {

    createMarker(markersArray.get(i).getLatitude(), markersArray.get(i).getLongitude(), markersArray.get(i).getTitle(), markersArray.get(i).getSnippet(), markersArray.get(i).getIconResID());
}

...

    protected void createMarker(double latitude, double longitude, String title, String snippet, int iconResID) {

        return googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                .anchor(0.5f, 0.5f)
                .title(title)
                .snippet(snippet);
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(iconResID)));
    }
```